# NSUserDefaults returning different value for key in two different classes

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

Pretty simple.. I have an iPhone app and I want to autolog people in if they have previously logged in within the last 30 days. I am storing the NSDate in the NSUserDefaults like so (username/pass in keychain):

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *lastLogin = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"last_login"];
[currentDefaults setObject:lastLogin forKey:@"login_info"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

Now there are two places where I check if this lastLogin dictionary exists:

1) The part of my code that responds to NotLoggedInExceptions thrown
    by my server. (Note: I've added the synchronize call even though I believe its only necessary for when you write values..)

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *loginInfo = [currentDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"login_info"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
NSDate *lastSeen = [loginInfo objectForKey:@"last_login"];
NSLog(@"%@",loginInfo);
```

2) On the very first screen people see. Due to
    latency it takes a while to wait for a not logged in exception so I
    want to simply throw up the login if the default value isn't there.

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *loginInfo = [currentDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"login_info"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

What happens is that the app opens. The very first screen goes through step 2 and thinks a previous login entry is saved so it lets code pass down to the server level. Now at the server level (step 1) the lastLogin dictionary is null! Aka my user defaults are producing two different values in different classes... despite the fact that I'm using standard defaults.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you no need to store `NSDate` as a Dictionary you simple store current time data at a login time in NSuserDefoult as a -

**SET**

```
 NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDate forKey:@"myDateKey"];
```

**GET**

```
 NSDate *myDate2 = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDateKey"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate2];

    NSLog(@"str get velue==%@",string );
```

and as par Your code you set like bellow code to store Currunt date time:-

> store date as a NSMutabel dictionary not as a Dictionary like bellow

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *lastLogin = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"last_login"];
    [currentDefaults setObject:lastLogin forKey:@"login_info"];
    [currentDefaults synchronize];

    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *loginInfo2 = [[currentDefaults2 dictionaryForKey:@"login_info"]mutableCopy];
    //while you get NSUserdefoult Nsmutabe Dictionary set code like this line with **mutableCopy**



    NSLog(@"%@",loginInfo2);
```

**OUTPUT IS**

> "last_login" = "2012-11-10 06:04:28 +0000";

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct because it has a lot of information. Some notes: Saving mutable objects to defaults changes them to immutable objects. NSDate is one of the types supported by nsuserdefaults out of the box (nice catch).